# duvida na elaboração de codigo

Tags: php, mysql

Não consegui fazer esse código retornar uma mensagem informando que não localizou os dados solicitados, preciso arrumar isso e a outra dúvida é que, mesmo sem colocar nada no campo de busca se eu apertar o botão de enviar ele retorna os primeiros itens do banco de dados, não sei como arrumar isso.

```
<?php
$servidor = "-";
$usuario = "-";
$senha = "";
$database = "-";
//Criar a conexao
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $database);

$pesquisar = $_POST['pesquisa'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `jazigos` WHERE `NOME` LIKE '%{$pesquisar}%' LIMIT 1";
$resultado_cemiterio = mysqli_query ($conn,$sql);


 while($rows_sql = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cemiterio, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    echo "<b>Nome do Falecido</b>: ". $rows_sql["NOME"]  ."<br>";
    echo "<b>Data de Nascimento</b>: ". $rows_sql["DATA DE NASCIMENTO"]  ."<br>";
    echo "<b>Data de Falecimento</b>: ". $rows_sql["DATA DE FALECIMENTO"]  ."<br>";
    echo "<b>Quadra</b>: 0". $rows_sql["QUADRA"]  ."<br>";
    echo "<b>Jazigo</b>: ". $rows_sql["JAZIGO"]  ."<br>";
    echo "<b>Gaveta</b>: 0". $rows_sql["GAVETA"]  ."<hr>";

}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize o `mysqli_num_rows()` para checar a quantidade de linhas retornadas na consulta `mysql`:
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Para não deixar o usuário submeter uma pesquisa vazia e assim trazer o primeiro resultado, trate o `POST` e 'bloqueie' caso vazio.

```
<?php
$servidor = "-";
$usuario = "-";
$senha = "";
$database = "-";
//Criar a conexao
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $database);

$pesquisar = trim($_POST['pesquisa']);

if($pesquisar=='') die("DIGITE ALGO PARA EFETUAR A BUSCA");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `jazigos` WHERE `NOME` LIKE '%{$pesquisar}%' LIMIT 1";
$resultado_cemiterio = mysqli_query ($conn,$sql);

$qtd = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_cemiterio));
if($qtd==0) die("NADA ENCONTRADO");

 while($rows_sql = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cemiterio, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    echo "<b>Nome do Falecido</b>: ". $rows_sql["NOME"]  ."<br>";
    echo "<b>Data de Nascimento</b>: ". $rows_sql["DATA DE NASCIMENTO"]  ."<br>";
    echo "<b>Data de Falecimento</b>: ". $rows_sql["DATA DE FALECIMENTO"]  ."<br>";
    echo "<b>Quadra</b>: 0". $rows_sql["QUADRA"]  ."<br>";
    echo "<b>Jazigo</b>: ". $rows_sql["JAZIGO"]  ."<br>";
    echo "<b>Gaveta</b>: 0". $rows_sql["GAVETA"]  ."<hr>";

}
?>
```

Comment: vou testar esse codigo

Comment: deu certo esse, e no caso do botao que mesmo com o campo de busca em branco, ele mostra os primeiros itens do banco de dados

Comment: @KaduSilva editada a resposta

Comment: nossa cara deu super certo, agora vou ver como fazer paginação,pois meu banco de dados tem 5 mil item e como e nome de pessoas, varias vezes aparece o mesmo nome na mesma pagina e fica muito grande

Comment: Veja `datatables`, é bom! https://datatables.net/

Comment: E marque minha resposta como válida. :)

Comment: vc sabe como fazer paginaçao?

Answer (score 1):

Para retornar a mensagem que não foi encontrado algo pode seguir a dica do @Pedro Augusto com o uso do [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-result.num-rows.php).

Para o problema que tens no botão enviar você poderia fazer uma validação simples com um IF + [empty](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.empty.php) antes de executar o seu `SELECT`.

No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
//...
//Criar a conexao
$conn = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha, $database);

$pesquisar = $_POST['pesquisa'];

if(empty($pesquisar)) die("Digite algo para pesquisar.");

$qtd = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_cemiterio));
if($qtd==0) die("NADA ENCONTRADO");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `jazigos` WHERE `NOME` LIKE '%{$pesquisar}%' LIMIT 1";
//...
```

Comment: vou testar aki agora para ver

Comment: essa die("Digite algo para pesquisar."); deu erro ) Erro de análise: erro de sintaxe, 'die' inesperado (T_EXIT) em C: \ wamp64 \ www \ teste \ pesquisa.php na linha 13

Comment: Estava faltando um parênteses no IF. O @Pedro Augusto editou agora, teste novamente.